# Updating package index is very slow due to large 'Contents' entries

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates

When updating my package index, e.g. over `apt update` it always has to download some very large entries, usually 20 - 40 MB with a *Contents-** prefix. This slows down the update process very much also due to the reason that it seems like these packages are fetched multiple times. Usually they are named something like *Contents-i386* or *Contents-amd64*.

I'm absolutely not sure if this is normal, but I'm a Ubuntu user for quiet some years and can't remember, that index updates where that heavy in the past. The problem could be related to some configuration change I had to made in the past but I can't really remember what it was.

Comment: Only a hind. `zless /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz`

Comment: Can you run `time sudo apt update` then copy and paste the results into your question with notes underneath of which lines took a long time? For me the time takes 7 seconds.

Answer (score 21):

Probably, `apt-file` was installed at some point and its entry (or "trigger" if i can say) got set in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

- You could keep `apt-file` and disable its config in `apt`, using this command:

  ```
    sudo sh /usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file-2-update.sh --install
  ```

  or Manually by commenting the lines in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf` by prepending `#`.

  Then you can use `apt update` & `apt-file update` separately as needed (Separation of concerns).
- Also you may tweak `/etc/apt/apt-file.conf` to set only needed indexes to be downloaded. Or Purge `apt-file` if not required any more.

**Reference:** [`man apt-file`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/apt-file.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, I removed apt-file in bionic, and wait some day to update it.

Comment: I install apt-file again Thanks a lot I make it the easy way `sudo sh /usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file-2-update.sh --install` At the moment I can not accept you answer.

Comment: @nobody Nice catch, I didn't know about it, first time to see it. I will update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @critop, das it also work for you? Have you apt-file installed?

Comment: I applied your solution some weeks ago and it worked like a charm, but now the issue is back and your solution is not helping. I also used `--uninstall` and then `--install` but it also didn't worked

Comment: @Ahwar, Script could be broken,  try settings  manually as in the previous version of this answer https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1184714/3

Comment: I just deleted my `apt-files` with command `sudo apt purge apt-file`. My question is that is there possibility that this action cause some issue in my OS?

Comment: @Ahwar no it is just an additional tool and usually used by advanced users or developers who need a manifest of all available files (inside packages) in the repository.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer @critop! Really helped me out. Why does `apt-file` add so much time to `apt update`??

Comment: @Jeff, because `apt-file` indexes are too large compared to apt package indexes. You may check it, just compare `Packages.gz` with `Contents-*.gz` for any repository.