# apt update now download additional huge data after installing package building tools

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Usually whenever I run `sudo apt update` the `apt`download small repository data in kB like these

```
Get: 24 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [638 kB]                                                
Get: 25 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [295 kB]                                               
Get: 26 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [295 kB]                                        
Get: 27 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [73,8 kB]                                          
Get: 28 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [143 kB]                                           
Get: 29 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [365 kB]
```

After following [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html) tutorial and installing some debian package building tools such as 
gnupg, pbuilder, ubuntu-dev-tools, and apt-file the `sudo apt update` now downloading extra data in order of MB:

```
Get: 30 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates i386 Contents (deb) [40,7 MB]                                              
Get: 31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security i386 Contents (deb) [36,0 MB]
```

Is this consequence of installing those tools? I have very slow internet network and want to revert this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating package index is very slow due to large 'Contents' entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152885/updating-package-index-is-very-slow-due-to-large-contents-entries)

Answer (score 1):

This is releated to `apt-file`

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf
```

[you can minimize the download size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152885/updating-package-index-is-very-slow-due-to-large-contents-entries/1184714#comment1980921_1184714)