# only fetch the diff when I run apt update on mobile phone with monthly data limit?

Tags: apt, mobile-broadband, bandwidth

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I connect to internet via mobile phone with monthly data limit. When I run

```
apt update
```

it fetches about 60 MB data from repositories. Is there a way to only fetch the diff between previous running of `apt update`?

EDIT:

```
sudo apt update 
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Sources [364 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Sources [9,912 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Sources [10.1 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Sources [146 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [795 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [192 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates amd64 Contents (deb) [29.7 MB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [143 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [21.3 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [736 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [152 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.9 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [5,076 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Sources [42.9 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Sources [122 kB]   
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Sources [8,960 B]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [480 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [105 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security amd64 Contents (deb) [23.6 MB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [120 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [17.6 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [532 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [532 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [74.5 kB]
```

Take a look at these :

```
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates amd64 Contents (deb) [29.7 MB]

Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security amd64 Contents (deb) [23.6 MB]
```

Comment: 60 MB? The official repositories' `Packages` and `Release` files only total about 15MB or so (compressed).

Comment: @muru I updated my question and posted `apt update` result.

Comment: `sudo apt purge apt-file`

Comment: @nobody, right  I have  installed `apt-file` but I need it.

Comment: Please try this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152885/updating-package-index-is-very-slow-due-to-large-contents-entries   I have no Idea what debian makes different from ubuntu. there I habe apt-file and never such large download size.

Comment: Do you really need apt-file? Most of what I can do can be done using http://packages.ubuntu.com, and for any other uses, do you need a regularly updated list? File lists change rarely.

Comment: @muru yes I need it, because I may not reach internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nobody has alluded to, these big files that you’re downloading are coming from `apt-file`. Based on [the docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt-get.8.html), you can configure this by modifying the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf` file and running `/usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file-2-update.sh`.

From there, you can set up a local cache for these `.deb` files with something like:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.cache/apt-file ~/.config
$ touch ~/.cache/apt-file/dpkg-status
$ sed '/^Dir::State/ d; /^Dir::Cache/ d;' \
       /usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file.conf \
       > ~/.config/apt-file.conf
$ cat <<EOF >> ~/.config/apt-file.conf
       Dir::State "$HOME/.cache/apt-file";
       Dir::Cache "$HOME/.cache/apt-file";
       Dir::State::status "$HOME/.cache/apt-file/dpkg-status";
```

From there you could update the `apt-file` cache independently from `apt` by calling:

```
$ apt-file -c ~/.config/apt-file.conf update
```

This was taken [directly from the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt-get.8.html), so some tweaking may be required.

Comment: Thank you @Matigo. Running `sudo sh /usr/share/doc/apt-file/examples/apt-file-2-update.sh --install` works. I just tried `apt update`, it only fetched 900KB of data.

Comment: Running `apt-file -c ~/.config/apt-file.conf update` gave errors:
`Reading package lists... Error!
E: List directory /$HOME/.cache/apt-file/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
E: flAbsPath on /$HOME/.cache/apt-file/$HOME/.cache/apt-file/dpkg-status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.`